# What means datacenter property in Spring Eureka server?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

In Spring Eureka server exists the property "datacenter",  what is the purpose of setting this? Do I need to set one if I am not running in standalone mode the server? Otherwise if I have zone/region for my peers, this property should have the same name to identify the zone they're?

For example

```
eureka.datacenter=myname
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described here https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Configuring-Eureka-in-AWS-Cloud it's required for AWS specific initialization

> In the AWS cloud environment, pass in the java commandline property -Deureka.datacenter=cloud so that the Eureka Client/Server knows to initialize the information specific to AWS cloud.